# Reading XML into Datatable gives incorrect DateTime when the time has Time Zone info

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, timezone

So my client runs some code that writes their current time to an xml file which I then want to read back into a data table but I am getting incorrect time information.

For example their current time is ***09:31*** their time zone is ***UTC+1:00***.

my code is:

```
var ds = new DataSet("MyDataSet");
var dt = ds.Tables.Add("MyDataTable");
dt.Columns.Add("MyDateTime", typeof(DateTime));

var startingDateTime = DateTime.Now;
dt.Rows.Add(startingDateTime);
String xmlDT = String.Empty;

using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    dt.WriteXml(memoryStream,XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
    xmlDT = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
}
string myFile = @"C:\Users\me\Documents\test1.txt"
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlDT);
doc.Save(myFile);
```

myFile now contains:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="MyDataTable" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="MyDataTable">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="MyDateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <MyDataTable>
    <MyDateTime>2015-02-12T09:31:37.4250365+01:00</MyDateTime>
  </MyDataTable>
</NewDataSet>
```

This file is then sent to my server in the UK ***(+00:00)*** where I then read the file using:

```
DataTable datatable2 = new DataTable();
datatable2.ReadXml(myFile);
```

and my datatable now contains 1 row that has a datetime of ***08:30*** but this is incorrect and I would like it to store the clients time. How would I do this with a change to either my client or server code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so client side you can add the line:

```
dt.Columns[0].DateTimeMode = DataSetDateTime.Unspecified;
```

or as a more generic method:

```
public static void RemoveTimezoneForDataSet(DataSet ds)
{
    foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {

            if (dc.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                dc.DateTimeMode = DataSetDateTime.Unspecified;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this saves the XML as:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="MyDataTable" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="MyDataTable">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="MyDateTime" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <MyDataTable>
    <MyDateTime>2015-02-12T09:13:39.8180356</MyDateTime>
  </MyDataTable>
</NewDataSet>
```

So the time gets serialized correctly on the server

Comment: But now you simply lose the time zone of the date. A date without a time zone information is meaningless in an application that has to handle multiple different timezones.

Comment: @sloth Good point, one of the draw backs of this method on the client means you do lose that extra information

Answer (score 1):

I suggest simply changing the type of the `MyDateTime` column to `string`.

Strings like `2015-02-12T09:31:37.4250365+01:00` can then easily parsed into a [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx), which makes handling dates of different timezones easier.

```
// note I changed +01:00 to +05:00 since I'm in de-DE (+01:00)
// to illustrate the difference
var offset = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2015-02-12T09:31:37.4250365+05:00");

//prints '12.02.2015 09:31:37' (the "original" date)
Console.WriteLine(offset.DateTime);      

//prints '12.02.2015 05:31:37 +01:00' (converted to local time)
Console.WriteLine(offset.ToLocalTime());
```

Comment: The only problem with this method is that i later feed the datatable into a Sql database and I would like to feed a datetime in rather than string. Although I could see this being a good client solution if I were to reconstruct the datatable on the server

Comment: You don't have to save the string in your database. SQL Server has a type called `datetimeoffset` that has time zone awareness. I just wanted to point out that you probably don't want to use `DateTime` in your `DataTable` since it will strip away the time zone information that is available in the xml.

Comment: @user1 It would help if you could explain what you want to achieve a little bit more. You could also strictly use UTC time (using e.g. `DateTime.ToUniversalTime()`) when storing the dates in your database; but it seems you just want to remove the time zone information? That seems like a bad idea. Just think about daylight saving time!