# How to Export/Import DateTime in DataSet C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I've two applications, 1st exports DataSet to file, 2nd reads that file to DataSet. Both application have CultureInfo set to "en-US", as well as DataSet.Locale is "en-US".

In first application I have DateTime field:

```
dt.Columns.Add("DateCreated", typeof(DateTime));
```

than write to file:

```
ds.WriteXml(fileName);
```

In second app:

```
    ds.ReadXml(reader);
```

and when I try to read DateTime field from DataRow:

```
DateTime? dateCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DateCreated"]);
```

it throws an exception:

'Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DateCreated"])' threw an exception of type 'System.FormatException' same as cast, or when I specify CultureInfo. Also it doesn't convert when I specify to save DataSet with Schema.

Date Value in this field is in format: "2017-06-11T08:10:06.2212339 03:00"

Why this happens and is it possible to convert it to DateTime without specifying DateFormat string? Thank you!

Comment: Show us the code for the entire method. Also show us a screenshot of the exception occurring, so we can see additional context.

Comment: The value does not look right - it should have a `+` or `-` sign instead of the space between the `9` and `0` (`03:00` is the offset from UTC)

Comment: So it threw a FormatException, but what is the message? In any case, @StephenMuecke is right, and that error throws FormatException with "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime". Simple to verify.

Comment: I've tried to replicate the problem with a DataSet and a DataTable and writing to and reading from a MemoryStream. Works well, so no luck there.

Comment: 'Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DateCreated"])' threw an exception of type 'System.FormatException'

Comment: Maybe that's bacause system locale is different? Because tools will work on different locales

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/a/3373348/34092 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UTC date string format seems incorrect without using positive or negative sign in time zone offset part, and will throw `FormatException` with given message `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`:

```
2017-06-11T08:10:06.2212339 03:00
                            ^
                            missing sign offset here
```

If date formats given by `DataRow` are fixed in positive time offset and you just want to read them, use [`String.Insert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx) to insert offset sign before offset part like this:

```
String date = (dr["DateCreated"] ?? String.Empty).ToString();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
{
    date = date.Insert((date.Length - 5), "+");

    // NB: Convert.ToDateTime will give same value as DateTime.ParseExact here
    DateTime? dateCreated = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF zzzz", 
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
}
```

The output string on `date` & `dateCreated` should be like this (in UTC basis):

```
date: 2017-06-11T08:10:06.2212339 +03:00

dateCreated: 6/11/2017 5:10:06 AM
```

NB: [`Convert.ToDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime(v=vs.110).aspx) probably uses `Object` argument instead of `string` in case of `DataRow` input, so this code may applicable if `dr["DateCreated"]` has certainly doesn't have null value:

```
DateTime? dateCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DateCreated"].ToString().Insert((date.Length - 6), "+"));
```

Parsing example: [.NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0LcGNT)

Related issues:

[Custom DateTime formats when using DataSet.WriteXml in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932071/custom-datetime-formats-when-using-dataset-writexml-in-net)

[Reading XML into Datatable gives incorrect DateTime when the time has Time Zone info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472824/reading-xml-into-datatable-gives-incorrect-datetime-when-the-time-has-time-zone)